# How to stop NeoVim from sending ^S character while I press Ctrl+S in Insert Mode?

Tags: powershell, neovim

I wanted to remap `<C-s>` to save a file. It works fine in normal mode. But when I'm in Insert Mode and I press `Ctrl+S`, it just send the character `^S` (as a single character).

I'm using Windows 10 and Powershell to open NeoVim. Is there a way that I can map Ctrl+S to save  the file in my current situation? Also should I stick to Powershell or should I switch to another terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I would try remapping it to something like

- leave insert mode
- save
- return to insert mode, after the cursor

```
inoremap <C-s> <Esc>:w<cr>a
```